Tutte polynomials of square grid graphs
I'd like to know the Tutte polynomial of the $n$-by-$n$ square grid graph for $n$ between 1 and 16. Criel Merino, in his paper "On the number of tilings of the rectangular board with T-tetrominoes" (Australasian Journal of Combinatorics, Volume 41 (2008), pages 107–114; https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/41/ajc_v41_p107.pdf), cites http://ada.fciencias.unam.mx/~rconde/tulic/ but the page seems to no longer exist. I tried using Mathematica's TuttePolynomial[] routine but it hangs up at $n=8$.

Do you need everything about Tutte polynomials, or only some particular data?

I would like the complete Tutte polynomials for those graphs so that I can evaluate them at various integer points. I know the polynomials will have many terms, but if I had the polynomials in some natural format (Mathematica format would be nice) then I could just have Mathematica plug in the values and give me the results.

You may try to play with the wayback machine. It recovers the web page you mentioned, but some links there are now defunct, so you will have to copy url's manually and try to recover those one by one. I was too lazy to run through the whole process, so I do not guarantee a successful recovery of anything (my attempt to get the source code failed), and the warning "So, if you try to use TuLiC on a BIG graph (>= 14 vertices and 92 edges) it probably won't be able to do it." on http://web.archive.org/web/20100324002641/http://ada.fciencias.unam.mx/~rconde/tulic/ is discouraging, but who knows?

Maple does not hang at $n=8$:
TuttePolynomial(GridGraph(n, n), x, y)
The output is very large, and you will want to run it on a powerful computer, but this may well work.

Have you tried contacting Criel Merino?

The TuLiC source code (referred to by Merino) can be downlowded here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235778821_TuLiC_v2_Java_source_code

Perhaps I should explain that what I really need are evaluations of those polynomials at many points $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers congruent to 3 mod 4. Since I’ll be looking at dozens of such points, I don’t see any alternative to knowing the full Tutte polynomials.

That is too big for current software. I can do up to 9 x 9 and might be able to complete 10 x 10 but no further. I think you will need some theory to do this. I would look at the statistical mechanics literature (Shrock, Sokal etc) but seeing you are obviously already familiar with that literature, I presume it leads nowhere.

To Gordon Royle: Back in 2008 (or shortly earlier) Rodolfo Conde was able to go as far as 12x12 (see Criel Merino's paper "On the number of tilings of the rectangular board with T-tetrominoes (https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/41/ajc_v41_p107.pdf). I will write to him to see if he's willing/able to go further with current CPUs.

To Carlo Beenakker: Thanks! If it were C code I would just compile it and run it, but it's Java code which is a pain to run and is not as efficient as C. If someone is willing to use TuLiC to compute those polynomials, they'll definitely have earned the bounty!

@JamesPropp Do you have a strong reason to believe that it is even possible to compute the Tutte polynomial with current capabilities for $n=16$? My understanding is that algorithmically it is a very difficult problem (hard to approximate for planar graphs) and all current algorithms are extremely slow (worse than exponential I think) - which would make the runtime blow up even for small $n$.

I didn’t make an effort to see how the running time would grow with $n$; I was guided by Moore’s Law (2008 was sixteen years ago) and wishful thinking.
